# Magento 2 - Upgrade From 2.4.2 to 2.4.4 Class "Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent" does not exist

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4.4, php8

I have tried to upgrade **Magento** From **2.4.2** *to* **2.4.4** with but getting below error while running any magento commands.

> Service with name "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand"
> could not be created. Reason: Class
> "Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent" does not
> exist
>
> Class "Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent"
> does not exist

Attached the SS. [image]

Comment: can you please run : composer update || composer  upgrade || composer install ,and try

Comment: Nothing happens, All commands I have tried.

Comment: which php version you have ?

Comment: I have tried using PHP 8.1

Comment: it is working now ?

Comment: I have checked in vendor also not found folder vendor/vertexinc, which are exist in M2.4.2.

Comment: can you please check in database using search "MigrateVertexInvoiceSent"

Comment: yes, in m2.4.4 not exist.

Comment: Still Not. I had removed using composer.

Answer (score 19):

I encountered this issue when upgrading to Adobe Commerce 2.4.4-p1. I was able to solve it by manually flushing the Redis cache databases being used by the instance. Sometimes the cache holds on to legacy data and causes these kind of issues.

Using the bin/magento or admin console to flush cache is not enough. You need to restart the redis cache server if possible or manually flush the cache using the redis-cli like the following example.

To flush a specific Redis cache database.

`redis-cli -n DB_NUMBER FLUSHDB`

To flush all Redis cache.

`redis-cli FLUSHALL`

Comment: flushing redis cache database solved the error message.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

in your magento 2 database search in whole database "MigrateVertexInvoiceSent" file or its path , if it is exist then delete it's entry from database ,And check